# Why is this code not returning desired result of 498.75?

Tags: python

I'm just starting out in Python, and struggling (mind melting here!) as to why the following code is not returning the desired result of 498.75. I've redone the operators 20 different ways and just can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't go further until i understand this. The code doesn't display properly when I copy and paste it for some reason, so just did a screen grab: [Pic from class of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1voC.jpg)
Much thanks,
-Cliff

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) Please add code, not images of code. Also, what input(s) are you providing to the program? It looks like you meant `oth = h - 40` rather than `oth = h>40`.

Comment: More info on [why we require code in text form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: what do you think ```oth = h > 40``` do in your code?

Answer (score 1):

`oth = h > 40` does not do what you think it does.  You want oth (overtime hours) to equal the hours above 40, but `h > 40` is a boolean expression that returns True or False, not the remainder above 40.

True is numerically equal to 1, so you are getting the wrong value when you multiply it by otr (overtime rate).

What you want is the overtime hours to be the difference between the entered hours and 40:

`oth = h - 40`

Comment: Thank you, Kurt! Yes, that seemed to solve the issue. This use of operators was not explicitly gone over yet in this class...only the general use of <, <= , > and >=...though the standard + and - and * were in fact mentioned, if not shown in use. 
Here is the solution I used for this: 

hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rate = input("Enter Rate:")
r = float(rate)
if h <=40 :
    pay = r * h
else :
    oth = h - 40
    otr = r*1.5
    pay = oth * otr + r*40
print(pay)

I'm sure their are more efficient syntax use, but I'm not there yet...